# How to create an array with repeated items using javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I create an array like the example below?
The first "column" is with mean of 100 and standard deviation of 50.
The second "column" repeat "apple" three times and then repeat "banana" three times then repeat...and I need only 120 "rows" in total.
Thanks very much if you could help!

```
value   category
120 apple
143 apple
87  apple
57  banana
90  banana
109 banana
143 apple
135 apple
85  apple
76  banana
112 banana
99  banana
```

Comment: Are you saying the first column should be randomly generated between 50 and 150?  Also you state that the second column is repeated two times, but in your example it appears to be 3 times.  And how should this be stored in an array - there are two values for each item.  An array of arrays?  An array of objects? A single array?  Your question is really not clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
var array = [
   { value: 120, category: 'apple' },
   { value: 143, category: 'apple' },
   { value ...
]
```

Above is an array of objects which contain the "columns" `value` and `category`.

You can loop through your rows and access the columns like so:

```
array.forEach(function(row) {
   console.log(row.value, row.category);
});
```